# jQuery button submit with enter key function

Tags: jquery

I have a button submit like this :

```
<input type="button" id="button_sign_in" class="button_sign_in" value="Sign in"/>
```

and I have jQuery submit like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#button_sign_in').click(function(){
             console.log('login');
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "login",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    if (data.status=='SUCCESS') 
                    {
                        window.location='home.php'; 
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#username').focus();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error:'+e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The problem is : we can't submit using enter key, so user must click the button Sign in to submit.

What I want ? set enter key into JS function, so user can choose submit using enter key or click the button Sign in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What else does the form consist of? That's what's going to determine how to fix the problem.

Comment: the button must be focused (using tab key) and then hit enter.

Comment: oh.. you wanted the presskey event on the button?.. it's the sample principal as described below.. $("#button_sign_in").bind("keypress", function(e){ //check for e.keyCode === 13.. if true do post })

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/hd7zqafg/

First click on the result frame (because there are another frames), and press enter, the submit button click event will fire on Enter key press & on button click.

```
$(document).ready(function()               
    {
        // enter keyd
        $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode==13){
                 $('#button_sign_in').trigger('click');
             }
        });

        $('#button_sign_in').click(function(){
            alert('You click submit!');
             console.log('login');
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "login",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    if (data.status=='SUCCESS') 
                    {
                        window.location='home.php'; 
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#button_sign_in').shake(4,6,700,'#CC2222');
                        $('#username').focus();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error:'+e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the call to `$.ajax` to a new function called something like `submitForm`.

Then bind that function to all the elements that can cause a submission:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax... etc.
}

$('#button_sign_in').on('click', submitForm);
$('#your_input_textbox').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        submitForm();
    }
});
```

Comment: I opted to duplicate the code in my sample for the debugger portion, but yeah.. a method call with a string argument is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the `input` in a form. If you press enter in the text box it will submit the form.

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" id="button_sign_in" class="button_sign_in" value="Sign in"/>
</form>
```

change the `input` type to `"submit"` and call `.submit()` instead of `.click()` on the `form`.

JS

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    console.log('login');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQ5fN/

Comment: Hi, I using button shake. So if I change the input type using submit type, the button wont work.

Comment: What do you mean by button shake? There isn't enough information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the form element's submit method is part of the form element, and has nothing to do with whether or not there is an instance of a input[type=submit] child element of that form.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type as submit and prevent default of your submit button. Also your submit button should be wrapped by a form.

$("form").on("submit", function() { return false; });

Comment: yeah.. OP gave an incomplete code sample, but what is the point of returning false on a form submit?.. or event bothering with event in general?.. he isn't attempting to submit the form as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 0):

If you only use jQuery.Ajax, certainly not be able to submission when you press *enter*.
You have to add `<form></form>` tag to realize it, and change the JS.

```
$('form').submit(function(){ //do ajax here })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event to the proper element (probably an input), which I assume is a 'username' (textbox) input or (more likely) the 'password' (password) input.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyxPu/

## **jQuery Section**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xhrJSON;
    $('#button_sign_in').click(function () {
        console.log('login');
        xhrJSON = $.ajax({
            url: "about:blank",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                    window.location = 'home.php';
                } else {
                    /*$('#button_sign_in').shake(4, 6, 700, '#CC2222');*/
                    $('#username').focus();
                    $("#debugger").append("<p>Button Click - Failed to 'Sign In'</p>")
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('error:' + e);
                $("#debugger").append("<p>Error - Button Click - Failed to 'Sign In'</p>")
            }
        });
    });
    $("#username").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            xhrJSON = $.ajax({
                url: "about:blank",
                type: "post",
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                        window.location = 'home.php';
                    } else {
                        /*$('#button_sign_in').shake(4, 6, 700, '#CC2222');*/
                        $('#username').focus();
                        $("#debugger").append("<p>Button Click - Failed to 'Sign In'</p>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#debugger").append("<p>Error - Keypress - Failed to 'Sign In'</p>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

## **HTML Section**

```
<form id="login_form">
    <input type="textbox" id="username" placeholder="User Name" />
    <input type="button" id="button_sign_in" value="Sign In" />
</form>
<div id="debugger"></div>
```

Comment: note, in this sample I changed the url to 'about:blank' and commented out the shake method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Cancel the default action, if needed
  event.preventDefault();
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```